# Stateful vs stateless (non web app) applications

Tags: python, state

I would like to understand the difference between stateful and stateless applications.

- What would be a non web app example of a python application which is
  stateless vs stateful?
- Would a script which scrapes the web and saves the results to disk be
  considered stateful and one which saves the results to a database
  stateless?
- What about dependencies? Is a script which needs other python
  libraries installed (dependencies) be considered stateful?

Most of what I researched (including this site) was regarding web apps and sessions, I am hoping to get a much broader understanding of this concept.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Technically, computers always have state, even if it is just program state.

So, in order to determine stateful/stateless as we commonly talk about, you have to have some notion of an interaction, request, or even a usage session, and the idea is that the behavior of a second interaction, request, or session does in no way depend on an earlier interaction, request, or session; then it is stateless.

> What would be a non web app example of a python application which is stateless vs stateful?

Let's define that an interaction with a calculator is opening the app, calculating, then closing the app.  And if such an app doesn't remember anything from one interaction to the next, then it is stateless.

A simpler example would be a REPL calculator that has no memory. Every command line you enter produces a result, but it doesn't remember anything from one command to the next.  Thus, each command is independent, and we can consider a run of commands as stateless.

> Would a script which scrapes the web and saves the results to disk be considered stateful and one which saves the results to a database stateless?

I would say that you have to look at the behavior of the script as a program as follows: does the script do something different each time it is run, based on the last run?  If so, it is stateful, if not it is stateless.  In other words, if the script looks at its last run and decides where to start based on that, then it is stateful from run to run.  If, however, it starts from scratch and powers thru a fixed set of urls each time, then it is stateless from run to run.

> What about dependencies? Is a script which needs other python libraries installed (dependencies) be considered stateful?

Dependency on other pieces of code can make a stateless program stateful.  However, libraries are often written as a collection of functions that give you back their state to hold in objects, so you have some control over how stateful they behave by throwing away or holding onto those objects.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up. So a web scraper which guarantees a website from a list of websites is crawled exactly once is a stateful tasks/job/service? This is because it needs to keep state to guarantee exactly one result for each site. Is this correct?

Comment: The question is whether the state is stored and reused (in any way consumed) from run to run.  If no state is stored from run to run then it is stateless.  If state is stored but not reused, then that state is merely *output* and it is also stateless.  However, if the state from one run is reused (read, consumed in any way, even just counted) in the next run, then that state is *memory*, not just output, and it is stateful from run to run.

Comment: Still, for a given program, we can find areas where short notion of run  to run uses state, and so describe some portion or algorithm as stateful, yet still for that same program if we speak of a longer notion of run to run, then we may call it stateless.  For example, if the program uses stateful memory, but we wrap it within a script or context that erases that memory, so it starts from scratch, then from this point of view it is stateless again from run to run  (that includes the wrapping script).

Comment: All that by saying you have to (get to) define the notion of run to run for a claim of stateless.  With REST and web servers, the common notion of run to run is that of a web page request / reply.  So, if the web server is stateless then one request/reply does not depend on the prior (or sequence of prior) request/replies.

Comment: With a scraper, if the notion of run to run means it stops and when it restarts uses the prior state to help it not revisit already visited web pages, then it is stateful from run to run.   However, in the extreme, you could say that every 6 months you throw out the state and start from scratch.  Then from those 6-month runs to the next such 6-month run, that it is stateless (even though within a single 6-month run it is stateful from restart to restart).  To recap, when you make a claim of statelessness, you get to specify the notion of the duration or what the run is.

Comment: Thank you so much, I get it now. You explained it very well!

Answer (score 2):

> Would a script which scrapes the web and saves the results to disk be considered stateful and one which saves the results to a database stateless?

In order to understand the "stateless" metaphor, you have to understand the concept of "independent, atomic operations." In a stateless system, each user interaction is some sort of complete operation.  Stateless systems don't hold temporary information over from one page to the next.  Rather, each operation is completely done, or not done at all.  It's not about the medium in which you store information.  The actual deciding factor is "can each operation run independently?"

Web pages are a good example of stateless systems, because the first page might run in a completely different application domain from the second, or even a different machine running in a different country.  While it's not really about location either, the fact that any page can run in any location is a good indicator that the pages can work on their own without being dependent on temporary data from other pages.

Comment: "Greenness disappears" - we implement an application that has state (from the user's perspective, as most apps do) using interactions that do not require state. Someone was thinking ahead. The real question is: do our stateless request servers run on a layer that has state? Yes! Everything wraps around to its opposite. The Buddha said: "*Both is, and is not. Neither is, nor is not.*" (That was before the Internet)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add more examples to the aforementioned responses. **Token based authentication** is considered **stateless** too.

Since the client will always send the token on every request, the server actually doesn't need to save state or create a session.

Also, the token is self-contained, all the necessary information is there to validate it, for instance, a token that is issued to a determinate source, can come again from another source. For example, a mobile application can get an token while is connected on a WIFI, and then continue sending request using another connection (on a 4G network) making the authentication system portable, which in the end is considered stateless.